# home permissins are still too generous

Tags: permissions, home, umask

<sub>i guess i'm still missing something, but after some time of researching (without any clear statements), i have to consult the experts:</sub>

i'm using Linux Mint MATE (Ubuntu based) and know, therefore a users home is world readable (`UMASK 022`) by default. IMHO a very bad practice!
i'm also aware of, that as long as "user and group are corresponding" (set by `USERGROUPS_ENAB` in `/etc/login.defs`), the umask for the group is ignored and the user value is also used for the group permission... so permissions for new folders/files are `775`/`664` (which is equal to `UMASK 002`).
i've also read a bunch of manuals, Q&As like [permissions 755 on /home/<user>/](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/95897/93768) etc...

IMHO better permissions would be `750`/`640` (`UMASK 027`), but i'm aware that i will only get `770`/`660`...
so i tried to "harden" the system and set `UMASK 027` in `/etc/login.defs`. i also checked `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `~/.profile` and `~/bashrc`, but i only saw a `#umask 022` (commented) in `~/.profile`.

so as far as i know everything should be fine and `UMASK 027` resp. `UMASK 007` from `/etc/login.defs` applied for new folders/files (after a restart).
**but** new folders/files now get the **permissions `755`/`644`**!?! so something changed, but not as planed! - funny: e.g. the new `apt.list` after adding a PPA now has the desired permissions `640`.

to be on the safe side i also changed the permissions of an existing home and its containing folders & files via `find $HOME/ -perm /o+rwx ! \( -path "$HOME/.*" -o -type l -o -xtype l \) -execdir chmod -c o-rwx "{}" \;` (excluded soft-links and dot-files to not mess around with them for now) to `??0`.
but still no luck, new folders/files (and i'm not talking about user templates) still have permissions `755`/`644`.

---

so what is defining system wide the permissions of new folders/files? ...or is preventing the system wide application of the `UMASK 027` set in `/etc/login.defs`?

Answer (score 1):

The `/etc/login.defs` file is the configuration file for the shadow password suite configuration file. From `man login.defs`:

```
This page is part of the shadow-utils (utilities
for managing accounts and shadow password files)
project.

Much of the functionality that used to be
provided by the shadow password suite is now
handled by PAM. Thus, /etc/login.defs is no
longer used by passwd(1), or less used by
login(1), and su(1). Please refer to the 
corresponding PAM configuration files instead.
```

Apparently, the value of `UMASK` in `/etc/login.defs` is not read by `login`. But it is read by the `pam_umask` PAM module, if the module is in use.

Comment: thank you for your heads up! - so `/etc/login.defs` is **not** read by `login` and my wrong assumption was that it applies `umask` system wide... so is there a possibility to apply `umask` globally?

Comment: You can enable the `pam_umask` PAM module. See `man pam_umask`. Or you could edit the files in `/etc/skel`, which `useradd` copies to the home directory of new users.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a file `/etc/profile.d/umask.sh` that contains your UMASK-setting. All files matching `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` are usually sourced by `/etc/profile`.

You can also set it directly in `/etc/profile`, but it may get overwritten by system updates in the future.

see https://superuser.com/a/671690

Answer (score 0):

If you're in multiple user system or managing one, you can set `umask` to `077` to restrict new created files and folders that only owner can be able to read/write/execute.

Change permissions to `022` when you want to install some packages.

Disclaimer: I don't understand your post much, so this just to give you some sense that the practice I used.

Comment: well... this is completely clear to me, but the problem is `umask 027` is not even working properly (and the group value is pointless at my setup), so `umask 077` won't work either.

Comment: is my or your bad english the problem why you don't understand the question? - if it is mine, please be more specific and give me some hints, that i can rephrase my question. (...and please excuse my bad english! ;-) )

Comment: I set `umask` in `.zshrc`. If you use bash, set it in `.bashrc`.

Comment: i know, that this is a possible workaround... but i'm asking for a global setting.